# Who was Nick Fury talking about on the ship?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, the-avengers-2012

In The Avengers film when they're all arguing on the airship (after they find out about Phase 2), who was Nick Fury talking about when he said a year ago someone came to Earth and leveled an area in a grudge match? I didn't take this to be a reference to Thor since Fury mentions that there are more things out there beside Earthlings and Asgardians.

Hope I paraphrased that correctly and didn't spoil anything; thanks.

Comment: “when they're all arguing on the airship (after they find out about Phase 2)” — “No Black Widow movie in Phase 2? Yet you’re doing Guardians of the freaking Galaxy? HULK SMASH”

Comment: Why the hell is this question still active?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

He was referring to Thor and the Destroyer destroying the town in New Mexico in the middle of their battle.

The other beings he spoke of were the other races beyond Earthlings and Asgardians - the Frost Giants, for example.

Comment: Another excellent example would be the Chitauri!!

Comment: True, but had he even learned of the Chitauri by this point in the movie?

Answer (score 24):

He was talking about the Destroyer from the Thor movie.

[image: Thor and the Destroyer face off amid wreckage of a town]

Answer (score -3):

he was talking about the kree and captain Marvel without mentioning any names. a lead up to Captain Marvel. there are hints about future films in every Marvel film you just have to spot them.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to support this?